# Trying to change appearance of list item dynamically with react and material UI

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, material-ui, next.js

I am using Nextron boiler plate https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron/tree/master/examples/with-javascript-material-ui

And I am looking for a way to change the appearance of a ListItem element when clicking on a button. I already have a ref on this element, and with material UI theme, I guess I just need to set my ListItem element to "selected" but I have no idea how to do so from my click event.

I also thought of adding a class to the ListItem and adding style to this class only, but couldn't find how to do so in material UI.

How can I do that? I have been looking for a solution for hours now.

Comment: the docs show you how to do this https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#selected-listitem

Comment: I was on this page and I completely didn't see that... Thank you >.<

Comment: Yeah I've done that before too lol